# How to change the display property of multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html

[image: List]

I have a list containing 4 buttons as shown in the picture.

I am trying to add a JavaScript function so that when a button is pressed, the relevant icon (right arrow) has its display property set to "block".

I can get the code working for the first button only, as shown, the function doesn't execute for the other buttons, however.

[image: on click list]

Here is my HTML code:

```
      <ul class="sec2drop">
        <li>
          <button onclick="myFunction()" class="collapsible">
            Prepare for a language exam
            <i class="fa fa-caret-right" id="arrow"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="content">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A
              veniam, blanditiis, dolores quasi quam, soluta porro ratione
              fugiat minus commodi in maxime amet fugit rerum magnam ducimus
              dignissimos quis non.
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button onclick="myFunction()" class="collapsible">
            Hungarian for kids
            <i class="fa fa-caret-right" id="arrow"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="content">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A
              veniam, blanditiis, dolores quasi quam, soluta porro ratione
              fugiat minus commodi in maxime amet fugit rerum magnam ducimus
              dignissimos quis non.
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("arrow");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: In HTML an id must be unique. You could also pass the id of what you are hovering into a function, instead of fetching different ids within that function.

Answer (score 1):

IDs can't be the same, because when you want to do `document.getElementById()` it will only return one object.

You need to change your IDs.

The code with changed IDs:
html:

```html
      <ul class="sec2drop">
        <li>
          <button onclick="myFunction()" class="collapsible">
            Prepare for a language exam
            <i class="fa fa-caret-right" id="arrow0"></i> <!-- CHANGED ID -->
          </button>
          <div class="content">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A
              veniam, blanditiis, dolores quasi quam, soluta porro ratione
              fugiat minus commodi in maxime amet fugit rerum magnam ducimus
              dignissimos quis non.
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button onclick="myFunction()" class="collapsible">
            Hungarian for kids
            <i class="fa fa-caret-right" id="arrow1"></i>  <!-- CHANGED ID -->
          </button>
          <div class="content">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A
              veniam, blanditiis, dolores quasi quam, soluta porro ratione
              fugiat minus commodi in maxime amet fugit rerum magnam ducimus
              dignissimos quis non.
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

js:

```js
function myFunction() {
  ARROWS = 2
  for(int i; i < ARROWS; i++){
    var x = document.getElementById(`arrow${i}`);
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

This js code will change ALL the arrows. If you want to change only one you can just use this:

```js
document.getElementById("Arrow0").style.display = "block" 
// this will change arrow0 display to "block"

// in function
function ToggleVisibility(Arrow_index) {
  Element = document.getElementById(`Arrow${Arrow_index}`)
  if (Element.style.display == "none"){
    Element.style.display = "block"    
  } else {
    Element.style.display = "none"
  }
}
```